# Juniper EX3300, how to use snmp to get the mac address list?

Tags: juniper

I am a network engineer at a middle network company,now we also use the traditional network architecture. While we deploy a new IDC point,we will meet the requite about how to identify a server with its mac-address,if we could get the mac list,I will work easy to make its vlan set.

I have done this with the network company HUAWEI, but I can't find the OID in Juniper,a very similar oid is "1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.40.1.5.1.4", but the result is the index number and the mac address, there was no number point to the interface number,so, any ideas?

The following is the part result about the command `"snmpwalk -v2c -c XXX -Cc 1.1.1.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.40.1.5.1.4"`

```
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.40.1.5.1.4.1.2.159 = Hex-STRING: E8 39 35 18 C6 69 
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.40.1.5.1.4.1.2.160 = Hex-STRING: E8 39 35 19 D3 5F 
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.40.1.5.1.4.1.2.161 = Hex-STRING: E8 39 35 19 D0 FD 
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.40.1.5.1.4.1.2.162 = Hex-STRING: E8 39 35 19 C8 79 
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.40.1.5.1.4.1.2.163 = Hex-STRING: E8 39 35 19 D7 65 
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.40.1.5.1.4.1.2.164 = Hex-STRING: E8 39 35 19 D7 69 
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.40.1.5.1.4.1.2.165 = Hex-STRING: 44 1E A1 71 A7 2B 
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.40.1.5.1.4.1.2.166 = Hex-STRING: E8 39 35 19 D2 C3 
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.40.1.5.1.4.1.2.167 = Hex-STRING: E8 39 35 19 C9 09 
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.40.1.5.1.4.1.2.168 = Hex-STRING: E8 39 35 19 D7 A3 
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.40.1.5.1.4.1.2.169 = Hex-STRING: E8 39 35 19 D1 61 
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.40.1.5.1.4.1.2.170 = Hex-STRING: E8 39 35 19 D1 7B 
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.40.1.5.1.4.1.2.171 = Hex-STRING: B4 99 BA AB D3 A5 
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.40.1.5.1.4.1.2.172 = Hex-STRING: 00 8C FA 01 12 48 
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.40.1.5.1.4.1.2.173 = Hex-STRING: E8 39 35 19 D2 09
```

Comment: Please use the command show snmp mib walk

Comment: I used the command, but after the key "walk", it must be with a oid, and the result is the same with the snmpwalk executed on the linux box.

Answer (score 1):

If you still need this, and I understand what you are after, try the following:

```
show snmp mib walk 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2
```

If that doesn't work, try this command and see if you can find the OID you are after:

```
show log snmp_reg_objs | match address
```